# How to stop a video in html 5 live streaming

Tags: javascript, html5-video, dom-events

I am a beginner in Javascript.
I have two buttons (start and stop) controlling the flow of mediastream using WebRTC. How could I create a event handler for stop button, which would stop the mediastream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reliable way I've found to do this is to change the `src` attribute to empty (or to some other URL).

Once you've changed the URL, the media will stop downloading in the background.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would this mean that if you reload the video it has to start downloading all over again?

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier, That depends on the browser.  I have seen browsers cache media that was not completely downloaded, but I doubt this is universal behavior.

Comment: Depends on browsers and user setting of course. thx for the quick pointer!

Comment: @Brad Well I just made the stop button(own button) link the stop button of the video control and also hidden the control. But thanks for your inputs !!

Comment: @user9135, Use a packet sniffer to make sure the data isn't still being downloaded.  In my testing, stopping or having a hidden element meant that the network request would still continue.

Comment: @Brad Good idea, haven't checked it.. Will test it.. Thanks for the advice.